# How do I upload blob file in Redux from?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am facing issue uploading blob file using the redux form.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class InputFileUpload extends Component {
  render () {
    const {input, dataAllowedFileExtensions} = this.props;

    const onInputChange = e => {
      e.preventDefault ();
      const files = [...e.target.files];
      input.onChange (files);
    };    
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          data-allowed-file-extensions={dataAllowedFileExtensions}
          onChange={onInputChange}
          type="file"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}  

export default InputFileUpload;
```

Field where the custom input is used

```
<Field
component={InputFileUpload}
dataAllowedFileExtensions=".pdf"
name="fileUpload"
type="application/pdf"
validate={[required]}
/>
```

Comment: What is the error or the issue?

Comment: It's not converted into blob format. Can you please help me.